# Can anyone explain how this plane could be used?

Tags: plane, tool-identification

This plane is listed on ebay as a carriage-maker plane but it does not look like one (i.e.: when I think carriage maker I think a jack plane size that can do rebates).

Can anyone explain why the sole looks like it is protruding and has those strange rounded sides (almost coffin shaped) and that weird metal inset?

[image: Weird plane sole]

Comment: I'm fairly sure you won't get a definitive Answer here on this, and possibly anywhere else, because this could be a nearly unique survivor of its type possibly even a user-made plane. My guess is this is as described, but the steel plate is a later addition. No clue why that would have been done though, it just turns this into a jack with an odd-shaped sole!

Comment: That being said, you ought to provide a close-up of the text along the side, or tell us what it says in the text of the question.

Comment: @jdv, those are just owner's stamps — F. Tweedale and F. Hatton if I read them correctly. I have no idea on the CC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's a **Coachbuilder's Door Check plane**.

After searching "felloes rebate plane" (I thought it could be used to make rebates on really large wheel felloes) I found this: http://cornishworkshop.blogspot.com/2007/09/check.html -

> It's a Coachbuilder's Door Check plane, s'what. In this case a "Coach
>   Door Smooth" for cleaning up rebates - for some reason called "checks"
>   by Coachbuilders. As it's curved it can do concave rebates curving in
>   the horizontal plane, which is nice.

Comment: Nice find! Now if we could only find out why the metal patch was put in place.

Comment: Great find! Maybe the iron patch was just put there afterwards to replace damaged wood by someone that did not know its real use? It seems to be only on one side as well...